# Why does my save_post action not trigger?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, save

I'm writing a plug-in for wordpress in classes and I'm adding an action hook to 'save_post' in the constructor of a class. However it does not seem to fire. Am I using it in the right way?

EDIT 25-05-2014 - I wrote a new (tested) minimal example that definitely reproduces the problem for me.

If I use the save_post in a procedural way (like directly in the index.php) it does work, but obviously that's not helpful when I'm structuring everything in classes.

```
/*
File index.php
This file handles the installation and bootstrapping of the plugin
*/
define("XX_POST_TYPE", 'testposttype');

if( !class_exists('MyPlugin') ):

class MyPlugin {
   var $savecontroller;

   public function __construct(){
      add_action('init', array($this, 'init'), 1);

      //include stuff before activation of theme        
      $this->include_before_theme();
   }
   //Include these before loading theme
   private function include_before_theme(){
      include_once("controllers/savecontroller.php");
   }

   public function init(){
      register_post_type( XX_POST_TYPE, 
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __('Tests'),
                'singular_name' => __('Test'),
                'add_new' => __('Add new test'),
                'add_new_item' => __('Add new test')
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'has_archive' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true
        )
      );
      add_action('add_meta_boxes', function(){
        $this->savecontroller = new SaveController();
      });
   }
}
function startup(){
   global $myPlugin;

   if( !isset($myPlugin) ){
      $myPlugin = new MyPlugin();
   }
   return $myPlugin;
}
//Initialize
startup();
endif;
?>
```

The save actions happen in a different class and file.

```
<?php
// file savecontroller.php
class SaveController{
   public function __construct(){
      add_meta_box('xx_field_box', 'Field', array($this, 'setup_field'), XX_POST_TYPE);
   }
   public function setup_field( $post ){
      ?>
      <input type="text" name="xx_custom_field" id="xx_custom_field" value="">
      <?php 
      add_action('save_post', array($this, 'save_my_post'), 1, 1); 
   }
   public function save_my_post($post_id){
      if(isset($_POST['xx_custom_field'])){
         update_post_meta($post_id, 'xx_custom_field', $_POST['xx_custom_field']);
      }
   }
}
?>
```

It does create my custom posttype and field so I know the classes are working. But the save_post is not triggered. It does not 'die()' and it does not do the 'update_post_meta()'. The custom field does appear in the POST request so the isset() checks out.

It's probably something dumb, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Ah sorry, didnt write that in my post. My init function is much larger and also includes other files. Also the savecontroller is included there. The rest of the classes is working just fine. If I put a die in the save function it doesnt fire.

Comment: Updated some of the code to reflect how I include the savecontroller

Comment: Your code works for me (after adjusting minor errors), the `save_post` does `die()`. Please, read [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) . . . ie: `The problem might not be in the part you suspect it is, but another part entirely.`

Comment: Alright, sorry. I just didn't think copying the whole classes in here would make the question clear, so I took only parts of it. Which minor errors did you adjust? Those might be the reason it's not working for me.

Comment: Well, as the article explains, you should **test** to see if your example reproduces your problem. Just make a blank plugin with the code and you'll see a couple of ***fatal errors***, I doubt they happen in the original.

Comment: Yeah yeah I did when you sent it, thanks. I will keep it in mind before making posts next time. I just thought that if you had found these things they might be related to my problem. But don't worry I won't bother you again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright thanks for the advice brasofilo. I've made a new example in an entire new and clean plugin. Disabled all other plugins, so I'm completely sure that this is the code that is creating the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add the hook `save_post` **inside** the `add_meta_box` callback, and that's not the place for it.

To solve it, change the `init` method to

```
public function init(){
    register_post_type( $args );
    $this->savecontroller = new SaveController();
}
```

And modify the `SaveController` to

```
class SaveController{
    public function __construct(){
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( $this, 'meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_my_post'), 10, 2 ); 
    }
    public function meta_box(){
        add_meta_box( 'xx_field_box', 'Field', array($this, 'setup_field'), XX_POST_TYPE );
    }
    public function setup_field( $post ){
        ?>
        <input type="text" name="xx_custom_field" id="xx_custom_field" value="">
        <?php 
    }
    public function save_my_post( $post_id, $post_object ){
        wp_die( '<pre>'. print_r( $post_object, true) . '</pre>' );
    }
}
```

Note that the `save_post` action takes two parameters and the priority can be default (`10`). You can find lots of examples for meta boxes and `save_post` [**here**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%2badd_meta_boxes%20%2bsave_post%20is%3aanswer).

Comment: Wow thanks, can't upvote yet, but this definitely saved my day!